# Increment a field to a unique integer when a field updates in Prisma

Tags: prisma

In my Prisma schema, I have a model that looks like this:

```
model Document {
  id                      String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt               DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt               DateTime @updatedAt
  draft                   Boolean  @default(true)
  publishedDocumentNumber Int?     @unique()
  text                    String?
}
```

When each document is created, it is in `draft` mode with the value set to true. It does not have a `publishedDocumentNumber` until it is officially published. When I publish a document, I will update the draft value like this:

```
prisma.draft.update({
  where: {
    id: req.body.id,
  },
  data: {
    draft: false,
  }
});
```

Since this document is no longer a draft, I want to safely auto-increment the `publishedDocumentNumber` value to the previous published `document`'s `publishedDocumentNumber` value + 1. I don't want to do a `prisma.document.count` since I could accidentally run into a collision if two documents are publish simultaneously (race condition), and they have to be unique.

Is there a better way to safely do this?

Comment: This might be easier to do at the database level. Could you mention what Database you're using?

Comment: @TasinIshmam I'm using Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Try using `serial` or `smallserial` as described in [the documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#postgresql-2)